# Integral of natural log of a function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I just need some help doing the following integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{R}\ln\left(1-\frac{ax}{b}\right)dx
$$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

I hope it's okay that I leave the upper bound simply as $R$ because the equation that describes it is a little long, and I just need to understand the form of the integral. I assume it's done by integration by parts, where $u=\ln\left(1-\frac{ax}{b}\right)$ and $dv=dx$. Doing this, I end up with:
$$
\int_{0}^{R}\ln\left(1-\frac{ax}{b}\right)dx=\\=x\ln\left(1-\frac{ax}{b}\right)\bigg|_{0}^R-\int_{0}^{R}\frac{-ax}{b-ax} dx
$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: In the second integral add and sub $b$: $\frac{(b-ax) - b}{b - ax} = 1 - \frac{1}{1 - \frac{a}{b}x}$

Comment: Why not substitue $u= 1-\frac {ax}b$?  So $du = -\frac abdx$ and $\int_0^R \ln (1-\frac {ax}b)dx = \int_1^{1-\frac abR} (-\frac ba\ln u )du$?

Comment: Anti-derivative of $\ln x$ is  $(x\ln x-x)$

Answer (score 2):

Your first step is correct. The integral then becomes $$\newcommand{\dif}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}} \begin{align*}\int_{0}^{R}\ln\left(1-\frac{ax}{b}\right) \dif x &= \left.x\ln\left(1-\frac{ax}{b}\right)\vphantom{\int}\right\rvert_{0}^{R} - \int_{0}^{R}\frac{-ax}{b-ax} \dif x \\ &= R\ln\left(1-\frac{aR}{b}\right)-\int_{0}^{R}\left(1-\frac{b}{b-ax}\right) \dif x \\ &= R\ln\left(1-\frac{aR}{b}\right)-\left.\left(x+\frac{b}{a}\ln(b-ax)\right)\vphantom{\int}\right\rvert_{0}^{R} \\ &= R\ln(b-aR)-R\ln(b)-R-\frac{b}{a}\ln(b-aR)+\frac{b}{a}\ln(b) \\ &= \left(R-\frac{b}{a}\right)\left(\ln(b-aR)-\ln(b)\right)-R \\ &= \left(R-\frac{b}{a}\right)\ln\left(1-\frac{aR}{b}\right)-R.\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let’s continue OP’s solution as below:

$$
\begin{aligned}\int_0^R \ln \left(1-\frac{a y}{b}\right) d x 
= & {\left[x \ln \left(1-\frac{a x}{b}\right)\right]_0^R-\int_0^R x \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{a x}{b}} \cdot-\frac{a}{b} d x } \\
= & R \ln \left(1-\frac{a R}{b}\right)+\int_0^R \frac{a x}{b-a x} d x \\
= & R \ln \left(1-\frac{a R}{b}\right)+\int_0^R \frac{b-c b-a x)}{b-a x} d x \\
= & R \ln \left(1-\frac{a R}{b}\right)+\left[-\frac{b}{a} \ln (b-a x )-x \right]_0^R\\
= & R \ln \left(1-\frac{a R}{b}\right)-\frac{b}{a} \ln |b-a R|-R+\frac{b}{a} \ln b \\
= & R \ln \left(1-\frac{a R}{b}\right)-\frac{b}{a} \ln \left(\frac{b-a R}{b}\right)-R \\
= & \left(R-\frac{b}{a}\right) \ln \left(1-\frac{a R}{b}\right)-R
\end{aligned}
$$

---

For simplicity, we better substitute $y=1-\frac{ax}{b}$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =-\frac{b}{a} \int_1^{1-\frac{a R}{b}} \ln y d y \\
& =-\frac{b}{a}[y \ln y-y]_1^{1-\frac{a R}{b}} \\
& =-\frac{b}{a}\left[\left(1-\frac{a R}{b}\right) \ln \left(1-\frac{a R}{b}\right)+\frac{a R}{b}\right] \\
& =\left(R-\frac{b}{a}\right) \ln \left(1-\frac{a R}{b}\right)-R
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thanks for identifying a slight mistake in my answer above!

Comment: It is my pleasure.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses! They were very helpful.